# Resolve dependency dependant on previous bind using Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm using Ninject as IoC and I'm following a tutorial to convert the ASP.NET Owin security default methods to follow the dependency injection pattern.

My database context, MongoDB in this case, is binded like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IMongoContext>().To<MongoContext>().InSingletonScope();
```

Currently, my security module (non dependency injection) is like this:

```
var users = MongoContext.Create().GetCollection<ApplicationUser>();
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(users));
```

I'd like to resolve UserStore like I've seen in this Unity resolution:

```
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(
        new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));
```

Well, the above code is using Entity Framework, in my case, it would be similar with my MongoContext.

I think It would be something similar to

```
kernel.Bind<IUserStore>.To<UserStore>().WithConstructorArgument(/*some extra option to pass a resolve of my MongoContext*/)
```

So I need to know how to pass the resolved MongoContext to the UserStore bind.

EDIT: IUserStore and UserStore are System classes, not mine.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Can't you simply give your `UserStore` a constructor which injects the `IMongoContext`? This would mean `WithConstructorArgument()` would not be necessary...

Comment: @NightOwl888 Updated

Comment: @timothyclifford UserStore is an Owin class, not mine

Comment: Why not just create a wrapper around UserStore and inject your MongoDb interface into *that*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some attempts, I think I've found an elegant solution:

```
kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().To<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
    .WithConstructorArgument(kernel.Get<IMongoContext>().GetCollection<ApplicationUser>());
```